# Special delete query

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I've got two tables:

- tags
- tags_news(binding)

I need to delete data which not contains `id` from `tags table`.

**Example**:

tags: 1, 2
tags_news: 2

There is no data with id=1 in tags_news. And I need to delete this. I don't know how. Please, help me.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: you want to delete from tags, right?

Comment: @John Smith, can you confirm the table you're looking to delete from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
DELETE tn FROM dbo.TagsNews tn
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Tags t
    WHERE t.ID = tn.ID
)
```

Comment: should this be deleting from `Tags` - or have I read this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from tags where id not in(select id from tags_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Left join` too, see below

```
DECLARE @tags TABLE ( id INT )
DECLARE @tags_news TABLE ( id INT )

INSERT  INTO @tags
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 1 )
INSERT  INTO @tags
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 2 )
INSERT  INTO @tags
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 3 )
INSERT  INTO @tags_news
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 2 )

DELETE  t
FROM    @tags AS t
        LEFT JOIN @tags_news tn ON t.id = tn.id
WHERE   tn.id IS NULL

SELECT  id
FROM    @tags
```